# Install program to single RDS user

Tags: remote-desktop, windows-installation, multiple-users, rds

I'm looking to install an application to a single user in a RDS environment without installing it to the other users. The user is an Admin. I have very little experience with GPO but imagine it's possible with that. A Google search only brings up how to put the server into exclusive mode (install to all users).

Is this even possible?

Thanks :)